# Ajax - Why isn't my remote rails form exucuting create.js.erb?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error each time i try to post a comment although when I refresh the paage comments are displayed

**HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR): POST - http://website.com/posts/37/comments**

in chrome I got

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

in my comments controller

```
if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          flash[:success] = 'Comment posted.'
        end
        format.js # JavaScript response
      end
    end
```

and I set the form to remote: true

so its supposed to execute the code in create.js.erb which is

```
console.log('working?')
alert('working?')
```

commenting is working but the format.js is not

heres the trace

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x007f3db84dd300>:0x007f3db9aff0e8>
Did you mean?  @comment):
    1: console.log('done')
    2: alert('done?')
    3: //$('comment-<%= comment.parent.id unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= "-".html_safe  unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= comment.id %>').load(location.href + " comment-<%= comment.parent.id unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= "-".html_safe  unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= comment.id %>");
    4: //$('comment-<%= comment.parent.id unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= "-".html_safe  unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= comment.id %>').html('<% j (render 'comments') %>')
    5: //console.log(comment.parent.id unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= "-".html_safe  unless comment.parent.blank? %><%= comment.id %>)
  app/views/comments/create.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_comments_create_js_erb___4383133957853497951_69951529166680'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:21:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (72.2ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace ?

Comment: The error page is not displayed, I got it in the console since its remote I can't see the trace. Is there other way to see the trace? [beginner]

Comment: You may be able to see the trace in the Rails log. In development, it would be in /path/to/app/log/development.log.

Comment: In `environments/production.rb`, comment out `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` or you can check `log/production.log`